# Entire .txt file is strings, but they're really not. How can I seperate them by type?

Tags: python, list

I have a that looks like this in a .txt file:

```
a
baby
*
27
int
```

After reading in the file, how would I go about separating this list into a list of 5 other lists?
For instance,

```
char_list = ['a']
str_list = ['baby']
special = ['*']
digit = [27]
data_type = ['int']
```

Is there a special function in python for this kind of separation?
I don't want to do something like

```
# I don't even know if this is legal
new_array = []
for x in foo:
    if x in "*"
        new_array.append(x)
```

Upon doing:

```
strz = [item for item in text if isinstance(item,str)]
print strz
```

It tells me that they're all strings.

Comment: You'd have to pretty much hardcode everything. Also, there's no char type in Python - those are considered strings of length 1.

Comment: Why would you want to separate numbers, chars and data types from strings? What is special about `*` anyway? I have a feeling that there is something wrong with the file format upstream.

Comment: When you read something from a file it will be a string, if the file contains integers then it will be a string not the integers. You can convert a string to an in via `int('123')`. If you want to see if a string can be converted to an int then you can just try `int()` and catch a `ValueError` if it is not an int.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a function that will check an input for it's type as you have specified above (with addition of floats).

```
def type_check(x):
    if not x:
        return 'none'
    try:
        int(x)
        return 'int'
    except:
        pass
    try:
        float(x)
        return 'float'
    except:
        pass
    if len(x)==1:
        if x.isalpha():
            return 'char'
        else:
            return 'special'
    if x in ('int','float','str'):
        return 'data_type'
    return 'str'
```

Now you can create a dictionary to keep track of each type as they occur.

```
from collections import defaultdict

type_dict = defaultdict(list)

# create a variable that mimics your file...
f = '''a
baby
*
27
int'''.split()

for line in f:
    t = type_check(line.strip())
    type_dict[t].append(line.strip())

type_dict
# returns:
defaultdict(list,
            {'char': ['a'],
             'data_type': ['int'],
             'int': ['27'],
             'special': ['*'],
             'str': ['baby']})
```

Comment: the int and float are confusing, if the line in the file is a float, the `try: int(x)` will be just fine, and it will return 'int' so 'float' will never be returned. Dont forget you can cast a float into int.

Comment: that is why attempting to coerce to float is second.  the input `'1.23'` cannot be cast to `int`, but it can be cast to `float`.

Answer (score 0):

You could write your own parser, but i don't suggest you to do so. Only if you insist - here is soultion example:

```
from collections import defaultdict
from string import punctuation
from string import ascii_letters

def parser(lines):
  parsed = defaultdict(list)

  for line in lines.splitlines():
    if line.isdigit():
      parsed['digits'].append(int(line))
    elif len(line) == 1:
      if line in ascii_letters:
        parsed['chars'].append(line)
      elif line in punctuation:
        parsed['specials'].append(line)
    else:
      if line in __builtins__:
        parsed['types'].append(line)
      else:
        parsed['strings'].append(line)
  return parsed

with open(your_file) as file:
    parsed = parser(file.read())
print(parsed)
```